# "Unrecognized image mode" in multipage tiff file while loading a specific tiff page

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library, tiff, image-conversion

We are trying to read multipage tiff file frame by frame using PIL.
In one multipage tiff file, with file Bit depth as 1 and compression as Group4
we are facing "Unrecognized image mode" error.

On analyzing this we found,
one page in the multipage tiff has image mode as "P" and compression as TIFF_LZW and when this page gets loaded by PIL, it throwing below error. Other page image mode are "1" and compression as GROUP4

`    self._ensure_mutable()

File "****\env\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 599, in _ensure_mutable

```
self._copy()
```

File "***\env\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 592, in _copy

```
self.load()
```

File "***\env\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1181, in load

```
return self._load_libtiff()
```

File "***\env\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1219, in _load_libtiff

```
Image.Image.load(self)
```

File "***\env\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 820, in load

```
self.im.putpalette(mode, arr)
```

ValueError: unrecognized image mode`

On further investigating this we found that, there is an image palatte associated with the image.So while trying to load any page in the image, it is calling this method -   `self.im.putpalette(mode, arr)`.Since one page is palettized it is trying to load the remaining pages also with the same property and failing.
This is my understanding on this

Comment: please amend the syntax errors in the code so
that other users can reproduce the problem quickly:
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Those are not syntax error. I just posted the error messages stating that it fails while loading the multipage tiff image. the asterik (*) symbol in the path are something i have added to hide the lib path name of my service